# Nested DIV not obeying auto

Tags: css, html, height

See image below. Notice the left and right borders are not filling the available space. These are nested divs. How do i get it to obey auto?

[image]

**CSS class MiddleLeftBorder and MiddleRightBorder are not working as expected.**

CSS Code below:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
body
{
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/Background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* TEMPLATE */
container
{
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
div.content
{
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1024px;
}
div.rows div.row
{
    clear: both;
    width: 1024px;
}
div.rows div.column
{
    float: left;
}
div.rows div.clear-row
{
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
div.logo
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/Logo.jpg');
    height: 150px;
    width: 510px;    
}
div.logoSpace
{
    background-color: #000000;   
}
div.menu
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/MenuBackground.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1024px;
}
div.topLeftBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/TopLeftBorder.jpg'); 
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;   
}
div.topMiddleBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/TopMiddleBorder.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 944px;
}
div.topRightBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/TopRightBorder.jpg'); 
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;   
}
div.middleLeftBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/MiddleLeftBorder.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
}
div.middleContent
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 944px;    
}
div.middleRightBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/MiddleRightBorder.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
}
div.bottomLeftBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/BottomLeftBorder.jpg'); 
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;   
}
div.bottomMiddleBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/BottomMiddleBorder.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 944px;
}
div.bottomRightBorder
{
    background: url('/CatwalkCloset/App_Themes/Default/Images/BottomRightBorder.jpg'); 
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;   
}
```

The HTML Code Below uses the CSS code above:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphMasterHead" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="fMaster" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="rows">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div class="logoSpace"></div>   
                    <div class="clear-row">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="menu"></div>    
                    <div class="clear-row">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="topLeftBorder"></div>
                    <div class="topMiddleBorder"></div>
                    <div class="topRightBorder"></div>  
                    <div class="clear-row">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="middleLeftBorder"></div>
                    <div class="middleContent"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphMasterBody" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></div>
                    <div class="middleRightBorder"></div>   
                    <div class="clear-row">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="bottomLeftBorder"></div>
                    <div class="bottomMiddleBorder"></div>
                    <div class="bottomRightBorder"></div>   
                    <div class="clear-row">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without some HTML all this CSS has no context.

Comment: Could you also please [trim down the example to only the **relevant** code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/162730)?

Comment: All the code is relevant. Without it, some confusion is bound to happen.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think all the colors, background-images, paddings, etc. etc. are irrelevant. You'll get better responses on SO if you remove all those kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using images for something which can be done with pure CSS (`border-radius`)? I mean that frame in `#content`. But ok..

First of all make sure that images are in path you wrote (use F12 and Network tab to see if there aren't any errors), because CSS classes and HTML markup looks correct. Not *good*, just *correct*.

Since you use fixed width for `.row`, `.middleContent`, `.middleLeftBorder` and `.middleRightBorder`, there's no need to use 3 images for buiding your background - you can use them combined as one background for `.row`. Also there's no need to use `div.clear-row` while you have `clear: both;` in `.row`

I think there's too much to improve here..

---

Ok, about rounded corners. You can achieve something what I think you want with this code (loosely related to yours):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Some text here</div>
</div>

<style>
#container {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
}
#content {
    padding: 30px; /* real content must be moved away from border */
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 138px; /* #container width - 2*padding - 2*border */
    border-radius: 20px; /* Basic CSS */
    -moz-border-radius: 20px; /* Mozilla */
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    -o-border-radius: 20px;  /* Opera */
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;  /* IE9+ */
}
</style>
```

You should get white rectangle with rounded corners on black background.

Comment: I'm no expert in CSS. So if there's an easy way to achieve a rounded border around the content... i'm all ears!

Comment: Hi. This solution did not work for me. I am using IE9. It shows a rectangular box with a black fill. And then a white rectangular border with text in it. No rounded corners.

Comment: Just use `-ms-border-radius: 20px;` for IE9+, I've updated my example.